# Iterate through Object List nested within Object using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to generate an email based on form input using reflection to make the email in a quicker and hopefully better way.

Iterating through the nested Lists within the Company object so that `_body` is a long output list of all properties within Company and it's nested object lists (`Asn` and `Contact`).

When the method accepts a Company object, it runs through each property in Company and checks what type it is. I'm coming undone on the checking the typeof List<>, I don't know why it isn't iterating through the collection.

I've been faffing with the code all morning but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Where am I going wrong?

**Basic model structure:**

```
public class Company {
public string name {get;set;}
public List<Asn> asns {get;set;}
public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Asn {
// string/int/bool properties
}
public class Company {
// string/int/bool properties
}
```

**Problem Method code:**

```
    public static void SendEmail(Company cm)
        {
                string _body = "";
                string _subject = "ASN Form Request";

                Type type = cm.GetType();
                Type type2 = cm.asns.GetType();
                Type type3 = cm.contacts.GetType();

                PropertyInfo[] companyProperties = type.GetProperties();
                PropertyInfo[] asnProperties = type2.GetProperties();
                PropertyInfo[] contactProperties = type3.GetProperties();

                foreach(PropertyInfo property in companyProperties)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType == typeof(int) || property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    _body += property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(cm, null) + Environment.NewLine;

                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<>)) // not running through the model properties
                        foreach(PropertyInfo asnproperty in asnProperties)
                        {
                            _body += asnproperty.Name + " = " + asnproperty.GetValue(cm, null) + Environment.NewLine;
                        }

                    if(property.PropertyType == typeof(List<>)) // not running through the model properties
                        foreach(PropertyInfo contactproperty in contactProperties)
                        {
                            _body += contactproperty.Name + " = " + contactproperty.GetValue(cm, null) + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                }
}
```

Comment: you should pull out the logic that reflects through objects from the send mail method. And then when you get to list you iterate through each item and recursively call the method again.

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to achieve. I find what has been posted pretty confusing.

Comment: @oliver apologies, I'll edit the Q, I'm trying to iterate through the nested Lists within the Company object so that `_body` is just a massive output list of all properties within Company and it's nested object lists.

Comment: Does typeof(list<>) need to have an object type in the carats for the List?

Comment: @LexWebb sounds like it's going in the right direction, didn't work but thank you :)

Comment: @PurpleSmurph I just tested this with this line : 
List<bool> t = new List<bool>();

            if(t.GetType() == typeof(List<bool>))
                Console.WriteLine("success");

And it worked with the bool in the carats but not without.

Comment: @LexWebb ok thanks for that, shall revisit to see if it was just me but Oliver's answer worked with some tweaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly your are wanting to output the company and any properties in the inner properties of the lists.

```
public static void SendEmail(Company cm)
{
  string _body = "";
  string _subject = "ASN Form Request";

  _body = ReflectObject(cm, _body)
}

public static string ReflectObject(object obj, string body)
{
  var type = obj.GetType();
  var properties = type.GetProperties();

  foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
  {
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType == typeof(int) || property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
      body += property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(cm, null) + Environment.NewLine;

    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<>))
    {
      var list = property.GetValue(obj, null)

      foreach(var item in list)
      {
        ReflectObject(item, body);
      }
    }
  }

  return body;
}
```

Comment: I can't make a small edit, but void can't return string.

Comment: @purplesmurth sorry about that. Notepad coding 

Comment: No worries, definitely the right track answer though, just ironing it out and trying to get it to run smoothly - not reading the lists correctly... Yet. Will update when fully working.

Comment: Adapted to guarantee no null and method will now accept any object through generics.

Comment: I'd like to know what your edits were so I can update my answer.

Comment: I've dumped the method I'm using into a jsfiddle html section [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kysg3tku/)